# How to make a drop-down menu in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow example of a drop-down menu in CSS from W3 Schools, but it doesn't work. I think I've copied everything exactly, but no result. However, when I copy and paste their code - everything works.

I've been trying to figure it out for 3 days, but no luck. Could someone tell what is wrong with my code, so I can learn from it, please?

Dropdown is meant to be on the last menu item - Articles.

```css
          .menu_box{
            background-color: #63707e;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 60px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
          }
          li a, .dropbtn {
            float: left;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 150%;
            width: 25%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1% 0;
            }
    
          .menu_box a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #c8dad3;
          }
    
          li.dropdown {
            position: relative;
          }
    
          .dropdown_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color:  #c8dad3;
          }
          .dropdown_content a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
          }
    
          .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
            display: block;
          }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul class="menu_box">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class = "dropbtn">Articles</a></li>
             <div class="dropdown_content">
               <a href="#">Accounting</a>
               <a href="#">Excel tips</a>
               <a href="#">Cars</a>
             </div>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try making a little targeted example without the `<html><body>` etc - in a jsFiddle or something. : ) https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c8r4wup1/

Comment: @sheriffderek He is required to make a [mcve]. Creating a jsfiddle for that will only get the question closed.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I've got where was my mistake - pretty silly.

Comment: @rob - is a code-snippet a requirement now? I guess I haven't been around in a while! : )

Comment: I was mainly suggesting a truely 'minimal' example... with less 'stuff'

Comment: @sheriffderek As long as I can remember it's been required.

Comment: Well, the built-in snippet stuff hasn't been around for that long... so - a minimum viable example - would have been a fiddle for most of SO's history. I'm not sure why any of the thousands of questions I've read weren't closed... - but maybe I've lost my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've closed off your `.dropdown` `<li>` element with a `</li>` directly after your `<a>` tag:

[image]

This closing `</li>` should come **after** the `.dropdown_content` `<div>`, making `.dropdown_content` a *child* of `.dropdown`, and thus to allow the selector `.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content` to target the dropdown content correctly.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
  <style>
    .menu_box {
      background-color: #63707e;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 60px;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    li a,
    .dropbtn {
      float: left;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 150%;
      width: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1% 0;
    }
    
    .menu_box a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #c8dad3;
    }
    
    li.dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown_content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #c8dad3;
    }
    
    .dropdown_content a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu_box">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Articles</a>
      <div class="dropdown_content">
        <a href="#">Accounting</a>
        <a href="#">Excel tips</a>
        <a href="#">Cars</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the li tag properly.

Nested list ( Structure )

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Nested list ( Example )

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Accounting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Excel tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the complete code

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
    background: darkorange;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0; 
}

li {
    color: #fff;
    background: grey;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.25s; 
}
  
li a {
    color: #fff;

}

li:hover {
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
    background: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Accounting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Excel tips</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed some the css below have mention your mistakes just correct it.Inside the code snipped I have mentioned the reasons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
    <style>
      .menu_box{
        background-color: #63707e;
        overflow: auto;
        line-height: 60px;  /** change height property to line-height so that you home,Experience ,Hobbies,Articles tabs will be aligned vertically center. **/
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
         }

        li{
       float:left;   /** you should add float left to li elements so that home, experience, hobbies, Articles will be displayed from left to right one after another **/
       }

        li a, .dropbtn {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;  /** use px for font-size **/  
        displayl:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px 14px;  /** give padding equally on all sides for better ui **/
        }    

        /** you have add on hover background color to li a:hover, not for .menu_box class **/
       li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #c8dad3;
       }

       li.dropdown { /** your li.dropdown should display inline block this inline-block helps to show the dropdown elements **/
         display:inline-block;
        }

       .dropdown_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color:  #c8dad3;
        z-index:1; /** you have include z-index:1 otherwise your dropdown will be not overolayed. **/
      }
      .dropdown_content a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;

      }    
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
        display: block;
      }    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="menu_box">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class = "dropbtn">Articles</a>  
         <div class="dropdown_content">
           <a href="#">Accounting</a>
           <a href="#">Excel tips</a>
           <a href="#">Cars</a>
         </div>
        </li> <!-- closing li tag should be here otherwise you dropdown won't work -->
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below I have added the modified code,Just check it. It now works fine.

```css
.menu_box{
background-color: #63707e;
overflow: auto;
line-height: 60px;  /** change height property to line-height so that you home,Experience ,Hobbies,Articles tabs will be aligned vertically center. **/
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
}

li{
float:left;   /** you should add float left to li elements so that home experience hobbies Articles will be displayed from left to right one after another **/
}

li a, .dropbtn {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;  /** use px for font-size **/  
displayl:inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px 14px;  /** give padding equally on all sides for better ui **/
}


/** you have add on hover background color to li a:hover, not for .menu_box class **/
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #c8dad3;
}

li.dropdown {   /** your li.dropdown should display inline block this inline-block hepls to show the dropdown elements **/
display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color:  #c8dad3;
z-index:1; /** you have include z-index:1 otherwise your dropdown will be not overolayed. **/
}
.dropdown_content a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="menu_box">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class = "dropbtn">Articles</a>  
<div class="dropdown_content">
<a href="#">Accounting</a>
<a href="#">Excel tips</a>
<a href="#">Cars</a>
</div>
</li> <!-- closing li tag should be here otherwise you dropdown won't work **/
</ul>
</body>
```